# Manage a new visual state in buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, visualstatemanager, visualstates

I want to add a new "Activated" state to a WPF Button and I want to avoid re-creating a control from scratch.

This new state is linked to the `IsActivated` dependency property and must change the background color of the Button. Here is the truth table of the interaction between the `IsEnabled` and `IsActivated` dependency properties:

[image: Truth table of relations between IsActivated and IsEnabled]

I wrote a class extending from Button, created dependency properties, and in the callback of `IsActivated`, I computed the visual state of the button.

The issue is that the ButtonBase type already manages the visual state through the [ChangeVisualState function](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Primitives/ButtonBase.cs,24002556222357cd,references), which cannot be overridden.

After managing callbacks of both dependency properties, the interaction between `IsActivated` and `IsEnabled` works as intended, but clicking on the button, or putting the mouse over the button overrides the `Activated` visual state.

Is this possible to accomplish this with visual states, or should I use simple triggers?

The code of the Control so far:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace OrganizationName.BasicControls.Primitive
{
    public class MultiStateButton : Button
    {
        static MultiStateButton()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MultiStateButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MultiStateButton)));
            IsEnabledProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MultiStateButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(propertyChangedCallback: IsEnabledCallback));
        }

        internal void ChangeVisualState(bool useTransitions)
        {
            if (!IsEnabled)
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Disabled", useTransitions);
            }
            else if (IsActivated)
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Activated", useTransitions);
            }
            else if (IsPressed)
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Pressed", useTransitions);
            }
            else
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Normal", useTransitions);
            }
        }

        #region IsEnabled override
        private static void IsEnabledCallback(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            MultiStateButton multiStateButton = o as MultiStateButton;
            if (multiStateButton == null) return;

            multiStateButton.ChangeVisualState(true);
        }
        #endregion IsEnabled override

        #region DP IsActivated 
        public bool IsActivated
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsActivatedProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsActivatedProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void IsActivatedCallback(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            MultiStateButton multiStateButton = o as MultiStateButton;
            if (multiStateButton == null) return;

            multiStateButton.ChangeVisualState(true);
        }

        private readonly static FrameworkPropertyMetadata IsActivatedMetadata = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
        {
            PropertyChangedCallback = IsActivatedCallback,
            DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
        };

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsActivatedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("IsActivated", typeof(bool), typeof(MultiStateButton), IsActivatedMetadata);
        #endregion DP IsActivated
    }
}
```

The default style of the button:

```
<sys:Double x:Key="ButtonCornerRadiusValue">5</sys:Double>

<CornerRadius x:Key="ButtonCornerRadius"
              TopLeft="{StaticResource ButtonCornerRadiusValue}"
              BottomLeft="{StaticResource ButtonCornerRadiusValue}"
              TopRight="{StaticResource ButtonCornerRadiusValue}"
              BottomRight="{StaticResource ButtonCornerRadiusValue}"/>
<CornerRadius x:Key="ButtonCornerRadiusLeft"
              TopLeft="{StaticResource ButtonCornerRadiusValue}"
              BottomLeft="{StaticResource ButtonCornerRadiusValue}"/>
<CornerRadius x:Key="ButtonCornerRadiusRight"
              TopRight="{StaticResource ButtonCornerRadiusValue}"
              BottomRight="{StaticResource ButtonCornerRadiusValue}"/>
<CornerRadius x:Key="ButtonCornerRadiusTop"
              TopRight="{StaticResource ButtonCornerRadiusValue}"
              TopLeft="{StaticResource ButtonCornerRadiusValue}"/>
<CornerRadius x:Key="ButtonCornerRadiusBottom"
              BottomLeft="{StaticResource ButtonCornerRadiusValue}"
              BottomRight="{StaticResource ButtonCornerRadiusValue}"/>

<Style x:Key="{x:Type primitives:MultiStateButton}"
       TargetType="{x:Type primitives:MultiStateButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type primitives:MultiStateButton}">
                <Border TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                        x:Name="Border"
                        CornerRadius="{StaticResource ButtonCornerRadius}"
                        Background="White"
                        BorderThickness="1">
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect Color="#CDD5E3"
                                          ShadowDepth="0"
                                          BlurRadius="13"
                                          Direction="0"/>
                    </Border.Effect>
                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                        <RadialGradientBrush Center="0.5,0.5"
                                             RadiusY="1"
                                             RadiusX="5"
                                             GradientOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                <GradientStopCollection>
                                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent"
                                                  Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent"
                                                  Offset="0.5" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource BorderPushedColor}"
                                                  Offset="0.8" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource BorderPushedColor}"
                                                  Offset="1" />
                                </GradientStopCollection>
                            </RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                        </RadialGradientBrush>
                    </Border.BorderBrush>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Width)"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="LeftBorder"
                                                     Duration="00:00:00"
                                                     To="10"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Width)"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="RightBorder"
                                                     Duration="00:00:00"
                                                     To="10"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Height)"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="TopBorder"
                                                     Duration="00:00:00"
                                                     To="10"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Height)"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="BottomBorder"
                                                     Duration="00:00:00"
                                                     To="10"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.BlurRadius)"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                     Duration="00:00:00"
                                                     To="10"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background)"
                                                                  Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SkyblueLight}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Activated">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background)"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ReflexBlue}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="2"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                          RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                        <Border BorderThickness="0"
                                Width="0"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                CornerRadius="{StaticResource ButtonCornerRadiusLeft}"
                                x:Name="LeftBorder">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="1,0.5" EndPoint="0,0.5">
                                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Transparent"/>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#D9DDE4"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>
                        <Border BorderThickness="0"
                                Width="0"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                CornerRadius="{StaticResource ButtonCornerRadiusRight}"
                                x:Name="RightBorder">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
                                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Transparent"/>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#D9DDE4"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>

                        <Border BorderThickness="0"
                                Height="0"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                CornerRadius="{StaticResource ButtonCornerRadiusTop}"
                                x:Name="TopBorder">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,1" EndPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Transparent"/>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#D9DDE4"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>

                        <Border BorderThickness="0"
                                Height="0"
                                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                CornerRadius="{StaticResource ButtonCornerRadiusBottom}"
                                x:Name="BottomBorder">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Transparent"/>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#D9DDE4"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused? Is there a reason you can't just use a `ToggleButton`? They exist to hold state in its `IsChecked` property.

Comment: @Tronald It's indeed something I overlooked for the IsActivated DP. Something to note is I trimed the class down, it currently contains other DPs used in the ControlTemplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to adding a simple visual state to an existing control, I typically avoid creating a subclass and instead use attached properties.

When it comes to implementing a new visual state for an existing control, you don't have to use the `VisualStateManager` at all. Especially if you aren't using animations.

I recommend using `Triggers` instead.

If you want to continue to use your `MultiStateButton` control, you can simply do something like this:

```
<ControlTemplate ...>
    ...
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                <Condition Property="IsActivated" Value="True" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ReflexBlue}" />
        </MultiTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

However, if you don't need to keep using `MultiStateButton`, I would keep your custom button style, and control template, and use an attached property class to add the new property.

```
public static class MultiStateButtonProperties
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsActivatedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsActivated", typeof(bool), typeof(MultiStateButtonProperties), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));

    public static bool GetIsActivated(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsActivatedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsActivated(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsActivatedProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Then, in your style's control template, you can use a MultiTrigger like the one above and do something like this:

```
<ControlTemplate ...>
    ...
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                <Condition Property="ap:MultiStateButtonProperties.IsActivated" Value="True" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ReflexBlue}" />
        </MultiTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It seems that triggers are the way to go but I wanted to be sure I was not overlooking something. I did not think about using attached properties instead. Thank you for your solution. Is there a drawback from using triggers instead of visual states? I only begin to use these so I wanted to solve the situation using visual states.

Comment: There really isn't much of a drawback using triggers. As a matter of fact, if you extract control templates with Blend for Visual Studio, you'll see that Microsoft is using triggers for almost all controls. I have built and maintain a large WPF theme library and now almost exclusively use triggers instead. A drawback of the VisualStateManager is that storyboards freeze resources. Triggers don't and are more dynamic.